# Best MySQL search query for multiple keywords in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, search, multiple-columns, keyword

The problem here is that i have multiple columns:

```
| artist | name | lyrics | content
```

I want to search in these columns by multiple keywords. The problem is that i can't make any good algorithm with LIKE or/and.
The best possibility is to search for each keyword in each column, but in that way i will get result that may contain the keyword in the `name` but will not contain the second keyword of `artist`. 
I want everything to be with **AND**, but this way, It will work for the keywords if there is only one column that i'm searching about. In other way, to receive a result, every of the column must have all keywords...

Is there any possibility someone to know what algorithm i have to create, that when you search with 3 keywords (ex: 1 for artist and 2 for name) to find the correct result?

Comment: can you add more sample with one example for output

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale in short:
`artist`='Justin Timberlake',
`name`='Like I Love You',
`lyrics`='And if you let go the music should groove your bones'. I want to have results when i search for: 'Justin Timberlake', 'Justin Like Love', 'Justin groove your bones'. The problem is when you use AND, if there is no Justin in the `name` than will not show any result. The method with FULLTEXT works almost, like i want it. But i can't search there part of words like is with LIKE %XXX% and the minimum chars are 4. There are still words like 'on, you, me, we, are', etc...

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is not to use MySQL for the search, but use a text-indexing tool like Apache Solr.

You could then run queries against Solr like:

```
name:"word" AND artist:"otherword"
```

It's pretty common to use Solr for indexing data even if you keep the original data in MySQL.

Not only would it give you the query flexibility you want, but it would run hundreds of times faster than using `LIKE '%word%'` queries on MySQL.

Another alternative is to use MySQL's builtin [fulltext indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) feature:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX myft ON mytable (artist, name, lyrics, content);

SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE MATCH(artist, name, lyrics, content) 
      AGAINST ('+word +otherword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But it's not as flexible if you want to search for words that occur in specific columns, unless you create a separate index on each column.

Comment: Ok, that works now... I try it last night, but i didn't know that i have to CREATE something... i just try the select...

Comment: However, there is a problem. Keywords under 4 chars are not displayed... For example if you search for 'Tanq' its ok, but if you search for 'Ego', there is no result...

Comment: Also how can i make that, if someone search part of a word ?

Comment: MySQL's fulltext index has no support for "stemming" or searching for word roots. You can use it only to search for full words.

Comment: Yes, the default minimum word size is 4 characters, controlled by the `innodb_ft_min_token_size` option. See documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: Than this can't be my solution that i'm searching about :(

Answer (score 0):

AND works for displaying multiple rows too. it just depends upon the rows you have in your table which you havent provided. PS, im sorry if my answer is not clear, i dont have the reputation to make it a comment